# Multiple always block using for loop

Tags: verilog, fpga

Is it posible to generate multiple always statements using a for loop in Verilog

By example. Let's say we want to create a 4bit Ripple/Asynchronous Counter.

We can do this like this

```
always @(posedge MainClock)
begin
    Q[0] = ~Q[0];
end

always @(posedge Q[0])
begin
    Q[1] = ~Q[1];
end

always @(posedge Q[1])
begin
    Q[2] = ~Q[2];
end

always @(posedge Q[2])
begin
    Q[3] = ~Q[3];
end
```

Is it posible to do something like this instead:

```
always @(posedge MainClock)
begin
    Q[0] = ~Q[0];
end

for (i = 1; i <= 3; i = i+1)
begin
   always @(posedge Q[i-1])
   begin
       Q[i] = ~Q[i];
   end
end
```

I know for a fact that the first methods works, because I tested it. The second method doesn't work, I did test it. Is there a different way to do that?

Comment: If you're going to synthesize that for an FPGA, you may have issues mixing logic and clocks like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `generate` to do that:

```
genvar i;
generate
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i = i+1) begin : ripple
        always @(posedge Q[i-1])
            Q[i] = ~Q[i];
    end
endgenerate
```

Comment: I vaguely remembered getting warning message when using an indexed name in the sensitivity list. But that might have been simulator specific...

Comment: this is ok for academic studies, but you might get a lot of surprises in simulation if you use non-clock signals as clocks in flops. you should use clocks instead.